# List all groups or users in directories recursively

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, security-groups

**Context**

Windows 2008 R2 infrastructure.

We manage network share permissions by AD security groups and put user objects in those groups.

**Objective**

I want to see what security groups are currently assigned to each folder on a particular server. I don't want to check each folder individually by right click > `Properties` > `Security` tab.

I want to perform some function recursively so I get a result something like this:

```
C:\                      - (DOMAIN\Group1)
C:\Folder1               - (DOMAIN\Group1)
C:\Folder1\subFolder1    - (DOMAIN\Group2)
C:\Folder2               - (DOMAIN\Group1)
```

Comment: Ok, so what have you tried so far? Which parts are working? Which parts are not?

Comment: None because I was unsuccessful on narrowing down accurate keywords that were relevant enough to yield results from Google.

Comment: Shame you removed your answer @jscott I was going to award it to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a pretty nice GUI tool for this called [AccessEnum](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897332.aspx) from SysInternals.

> While the flexible security model employed by Windows NT-based systems allows full control over security and file permissions, managing permissions so that users have appropriate access to files, directories and Registry keys can be difficult. There's no built-in way to quickly view user accesses to a tree of directories or keys. AccessEnum gives you a full view of your file system and Registry security settings in seconds, making it the ideal tool for helping you for security holes and lock down permissions where necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the permissions on folders then this powershell command will give show you

```
 Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where { $_.PSIsContainer } | Get-Acl | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Comment: Whilst this gave me exactly what I wanted, the format of which it ouputted wasn't ideal and difficult to sort/filter/manipulate in Excel.

Comment: @adampski experiment with the export-csv cmdlet

Comment: This was not achievable due to the layout of the output, with or without `Format-Table`